# How to Pass URL Variables to a Form in Silverstripe

Tags: php, silverstripe

I am working on a custom email form that should be able to handle the following URLs:

```
http://www.example.com/email
```

Defaults to general email address.

```
http://www.example.com/email/Office/1
```

Gets email contact details from Office model, ID 1

```
http://www.example.com/email/Staff/96
```

Gets email contact details from Staff model, ID 96

I thought I could do this by accessing the normal $Action/$ID variables - but got utterly confused by the Routing documentation: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.3/developer_guides/controllers/routing/

```
class EmailPage_Controller extends Page_Controller
{

  private static $allowed_actions = array(
    'Form',
    'Staff',
    'Office'
    );

  public function Form() { 

    $Action = $this->request->getVar('Action');
    $ID = $this->request->getVar('ID');
```

Doesn't work.

What's the best way of accessing/ passing URL variables to a form in Silverstripe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ID = $this->request->param('ID');
```

This will get you the id from the Url parameters as you have defined them in your routes or $url_handlers.The same method is used to get the action parameter.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed to do. I normally used param() but must of copy/pasted getVar() from some other code.